# Как взять данные с карточки контактов python?

Tags: python, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на кнопку контакты, становится доступная вся инфа про магазин. Как ее спарсить?
Я получаю массив данных из 300 магазинов и мне необходимо собрать там данные. Открытого API конечно же нет. Подскажите. При помощи силениум тоже не подходит.

Comment: а в чем проблема с selenium?

Comment: ни в чем. При помощи selenium необходимо в браузере открывать ссылку, потом нажимать кнопку, получать новый html и только потом брать инфу. Так вот может есть методы быстрее. Ладно так несколько ссылок. А если 1000 нужна и больше.

Comment: Используйте асинхронные аналоги selenium, например playwright.

Comment: сейчас посмотрю, спасибо